# Where to keep h:messages in a h:datatable while validating two h:columns

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am using one h:selectbooleancheckbox in each row to make 2 columns editable.

Have a look at my JSF page

```
<h:dataTable id="editTable" styleClass = "listtable" value="#{bean.GroupList}"  var="group" border="1" first="0" rows="8" width="75%" frame="hsides" rules="all" cellpadding="5" headerClass="tableheading" rowClasses="firstrow, secondrow">

    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Groups"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="GroupId"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered="#{not bean.checked[group.Id]}"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" required="true"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="GroupName"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered="#{not bean.checked[group.Id]}"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" required="true"/>
    </h:column>


    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Check to Enable/Disable"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" />
    </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

I have required="true" for GroupId and GroupName columns.

I am not getting where to keep h:messages for each column to display requiredmessage

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<h:message>` instead to display errors specific to an input element. The `<h:messages>` will display *all* messages which are not covered by any `<h:message>`.

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="GroupId"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered="#{not bean.checked[group.Id]}"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText id="groupId" value="#{group.Id}" rendered="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" required="true"/>
    <h:message for="groupId" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="GroupName"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered="#{not bean.checked[group.Id]}"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText id="groupName" value="#{group.Name}" rendered="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" required="true"/>
    <h:message for="groupName" />
</h:column>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response BalusC.I actually meant to ask about where to place h:message only.Is there any way to present the h:message in separate column so that the datatable cell is not cluttered?

Comment: Truly, just put it in another `<h:column>`. This column will only be *always* rendered. Whether that's an issue or not depends on the layout/style.

Comment: Ok.Column being always rendered is not an good option for me.Instead it would be better to use h:messages on the top of h:datatable to show all errormessages.What do you say?

Comment: Your site. Your requirements. Your choice :) Both are fine.

Comment: Thank you.I will try both and see which fits better for my layout.

Comment: @Sreeram: If you omit the column header for your message column and have no background color or cell borders, the empty message column shouldn't bother too much.